# What are the requirements for window to be blurred, except SetWindowCompositionAttribute call?

Tags: c++, winapi, blur, dwm

I have a dll library that deals with windows: you can simply create windows, draw graphics, etc. Also this library provides you to make blurred windows for Win7 and Win10.

I have two almost same builds of library - one , older without sources, and one newer with sources.

I am writing some app in Win10 and have been using old library, but now decided to compile new build. It works almost the same, as I said, except blur - it doesn’t work. Here is the client code:

```
HWND hwnd; // here stored window created by library function

struct ACCENTPOLICY
{
  int na;
  int nf;
  int nc;
  int nA;
};
struct WINCOMPATTRDATA
{
  int na;
  PVOID pd;
  ULONG ul;
};

const HINSTANCE hm = LoadLibrary(L"user32.dll");
if (hm)
{
  typedef BOOL(WINAPI*pSetWindowCompositionAttribute)(HWND, WINCOMPATTRDATA*);

  const pSetWindowCompositionAttribute SetWindowCompositionAttribute = (pSetWindowCompositionAttribute)GetProcAddress(hm, "SetWindowCompositionAttribute");
  if (SetWindowCompositionAttribute)
  {
    ACCENTPOLICY policy = { 3, 0, 0, 0 }; // and even works 4,0,155,0 (Acrylic blur)
    WINCOMPATTRDATA data = { 19, &policy,sizeof(ACCENTPOLICY) };
    SetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, &data);
  }
  FreeLibrary(hm);
}
```

It completely works in old library and doesn’t work in new - window is not transparent at all, and hence no blur.

**Details**

I am calling function from my library, that creates window, returns hwnd, then set background color with alfa, and then run code above. Nothing else.

In sources I have, window creates as `CreateWindowEx` without `WS_EX_LAYERED`. I tried to add this flag, add `DwmBlurBehindWindow` call, add `SetLayeredWindowAttribute` with `LWA_ALPHA` or `LWA_COLORKEY`, but the only result I got - transparency, without any blur.

Here is some code from `WM_PAINT`:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
hdcc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
BITMAPINFO bmi;
LPBYTE bits;

ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));

bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

bm = CreateDIBSection(hdcc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bits, NULL, 0);

//All draws here. The first one is Gdi+ background draw with alfa brush

SetStretchBltMode(hdc, COLORONCOLOR);
SetStretchBltMode(hdcc, COLORONCOLOR);

StretchBlt(hdc, ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.top, ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top, hdcc, 0, 0, ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left, ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top, SRCCOPY);
EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
```

What did I miss?

---

Old library, same code in client:

[image]

New library, `DwmBlurBehindWindow` call, setting `WS_EX_LAYERED` or `SetLayeredWindowAttribute` calling doesn’t make any effect, same code in client:

[image]

New library, without `DwmBlurBehindWindow`, same code in client:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what I did, but now it works.

First of all, I should say, that library provides not just function, but an interface - abstract class.

The second one - HWND of created window is actually doesn’t returns, because function that creates window is void. I found window by `FindWindow()`.

`GetLastError()` after `SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` returned 6, but now, if when it works it returns 10 - ERROR_BAD_ENVIRONMENT
10 (0xA)
The environment is incorrect.

Also I was getting crashes trying to call `MessageBox()` to display the error code. The program crashed even if I just check whether `hwnd` equals to `NULL` or not.

**Summary**

As I mentioned in question, I decided to make new build, because I wanted sone new features.
Seems, the abstract interface class in current fresh dll is not the same as in client, but in the old one dll is. I think the problem is in this.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Although I don't know specifically what was the hurdle, but [here](https://github.com/putara/dragdrop) is a project which does what you want and works well. It might be the use of buffered painting, or something else. Thought it could help you though.